# Как настроить карты на сайте?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, веб-программирование, google-maps

Создал тестовую версию на [этом](http://bloodfire.inf.ua/) сайте. Никак не получается запустить карту, но при нажатии на F12 (средства разработчика), когда модальное окно открыто, карта сразу появляется, с чем это связано и почему маркер не по центру? Помогите разобраться. Огромное спасибо наперед!

Comment: приведите пример кода где вы запускаете(подключаете) карту на сайт

Comment: код можно посмотреть прямо на странице сайта, все запихнул в index.html

Comment: вероятно, при нажатии F12 браузер переходит в режим адаптива под другое разрешение, например, и контейнер с картой принимает доступный для отображения карты вид

Comment: я нашел похожий вопрос на английском stackoveflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197128/google-maps-api-v3-not-rendering-competely-on-tabbed-page-using-twitters-bootst. Похоже, что все дело в том, что карта инициализируется до того, как становится видимой. Попробуйте инициализировать карту после открытия модального окна.